# SVN Sync to folder on commit

Tags: svn, svnsync

I have an exploded www folder containing my whole php website.

I wonder if something like this is possible:

- developers don't work directly on the files
- changes are tested locally or on a staging server
- svn commits trigger an event which synchronizes latest changes made to the repo, to the www folder

I heard about svnsync / svnexport tools but how can I trigger them on commits or make them "listening" to my repo?

In addition, can they update just the changed files? My repo is very big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People do this so often that it's in [the official Subversion FAQ](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#website-auto-update)

Short version:

1. Make your `www` directory a working copy
2. Create a post-commit hook which executes `svn update` against that working copy.

If your repository server doesn't have direct access to the web server (which it shouldn't), you'd be better off with this:

1. Create a working copy on the repository server or an intermediate server
2. Create a post-commit hook which executes `svn update` against that working copy
3. `rsync` that working copy to your web server (this could be part of the post-comit hook script)

Yet *another* option would be to use a Continuous Integration server to monitor the repository changes and deploy them. In fact, that is the best way to go for most shops. You'd use the CI server to update a staging server and then only push to the live server after testing is completed. Then your developers will work **only** in a local, private-to-them working copy.